# MySql Pass value from a select to variables

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySql, how can I load values from a select that's inside a function, into variables inside a function?

That select returns only a single row.

**Table**

```
"id"    "type"  "parent"    "userName"  "userId"    "country"
"5"     "1"     "1"         "norman"    "1"         "US"
"6"     "2"     "5"         "norman"    "1"         "US"
"7"     "3"     "6"         "norman"    "1"         "US"
"8"     "10"    "7"         "norman"    "1"         "US"
"9"     "1"     "1"         "james"     "2"         "UK"
```

**Function**

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `mainLinks`(`id` INT)
    RETURNS varchar(1500)
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN

//Something like this:
DECLARE i INT(10);
SET i = id;
select id, type, parent, userName, userId, country from myTable where id=i;
//Load values from the above select into variables that can be used all over the function. Here's where I'm stuck.
SET nId = id;
SET nType = type;
//etc

//I'll then use concat to display the output.  
return (select concat(nId,' ~ ',nType));
It's a lot more complicated than this and needs to go this way. I've kept it this way for this question.

END
```

I call the function this way `SELECT id, mainLinks(id) from mytable;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`SELECT ... INTO var_list`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html)

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION mainLinks(nid INT)
RETURNS varchar(1500)
BEGIN
  DECLARE aid INT;
  DECLARE atype INT;
  DECLARE aparent INT;
  DECLARE ausername VARCHAR(32);
  DECLARE auserid INT;
  DECLARE aCOUNTRY VARCHAR(2);

  SELECT id, type, parent, userName, userId, country
    INTO aid, atype, aparent, auserName, auserId, acountry
    FROM Table1
   WHERE id = nid;

  RETURN CONCAT(aid, atype, aparent, auserName, auserId, acountry);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Use:

```
SELECT mainLinks(5);
```

Output:

```
|         LINK |
----------------
| 511norman1US |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c377/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks, Peter. You saved me twice today. I never knew it could be done like this.